# Text is being hidden but I can't find where in the css

Tags: css

The success stories on this page (http://www.eupraxia.us/success-stories/ - the second one for Mark in particular) are having their text cut off.  I found one instance over overflow:hidden in the main css stylesheet and in the plugin's files. Nothing changed when I removed it, so I added it back in. Also tried noodling around with height which also did nothing. Any idea why the text is getting cut off?  Thanks!

Comment: use your browser's DOM inspector to figure out why. it'll tell you ALL of the styles being applied to an element, and where the styles originate from.

Comment: Your site've been hacked (or you're a spammer but in case of doubt, let's say it's the former ;) ). I can see (in Firebug) absolutely positioned text like `cialis online`, `buy viagra (...)` , etc at the end of Mark testimony

Comment: You can see it pretty easily if you don't display CSS. In Firefox, `Display / Style of page / No style`. They're generated server side because I can still see them if I desactivate JavaScript. And for information, I'm from France and the first link is written in french "comme le viagra". It's not a dumb script if it verifies the language accepted by the browser and/or country of IP...

Comment: thanks for the spam tip - just took over this site a week ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's standard way of js carousel implementation. Other parts are hidden because parent element `overflow` is set to `hidden`, what makes all content that extends it's `height` and `width` invisible.

```
<div id="slider" style="width: 641px; height: 782px; overflow: hidden;">
```